# TinyMCE - Loading Html from other Textareas

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I load html into a series of textareas, which I give a style of display:none;
I then have a nice dropdown menu with options that hold the values of each textarea's ID attribute.

I have jquery listening to the change of the dropdown and when the ID is detected, I load the value of that corresponding textarea into a primary textarea with the lovely TinyMCE plugin.

It all works fine, without TinyMCE.  But the editor just won't show the dynamically loaded html text.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
<textarea id="template1"><div>Some html <b>inside this textarea</b><br>And more</textarea>
<textarea id="template2"><div>More html <b>inside this textarea</b><br>And more</textarea>

<select name="templateid" id="templateid"> 
  <option value="0">-------------</option>
  <option value="1">Load Template 1</option>
  <option value="2">Load Template 2</option>
</select>

<textarea id="maintemplate"></textarea>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#templateid").change(function(){ 
    var templateid = $(this).val();
    if(templateid == 0){ $("#templatetext").val(""); return false; }
    var html = $("#template"+templateid).val();
    $("#maintemplate").val(html); // this is ignored?
    return false;   
});


$("textarea#maintemplate").tinymce({
    script_url : '/includes/modules/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',// Location of TinyMCE script
    // General options
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    /*forced_root_block : '',*/
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleprops,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,removeformat,code,|,cleanup,preview",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
});

});
</script>
```

You'll see: `$("#maintemplate").val(html);` is where I'm loading the values of the other textareas.  But the editor is just not displaying it.  (without the editor, it works)

Comment: Not positive but I think something like this `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(html);` in place of `$("#maintemplate").val(html); `

Answer (score 1):

**Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?**

Here is a working [DEMO](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/69caab/1) of your code(pasted as it is) ....

The only thing i can point out is that you are not loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jscripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!!!